# Moving password validation errors for Django UserCreationForm, from password2, to password1

Tags: python, django, ajax, validation, inheritance

I've got a Django form class, that inherits from the built-in UserCreationForm.

I'm working on submitting the form using AJAX, and returning the bound form (including errors) as rendered HTML if it doesn't validate.

Something puzzling me is that the errors relating to the password (e.g. too short, common password...) appear for the password2 / confirmation field. Here's a screenshot of the default behaviour:
[image]

From a UX perspective I feel as though it would be more useful for the errors to appear for the first password field in the form, so users can adjust that one, then confirm it by typing it again below.

I've noticed that in [UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py), clean_password2(), doesn't actually validate the password, it just checks that password1 and password2 match. Then in the _post_clean() method, password2 is validated, and any errors are added to that field.

In my attempt to change it, I have overridden _post_clean() as follows:

```
def _post_clean(self):
    super(forms.ModelForm, self)._post_clean()
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    if password:
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
        except forms.ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password1', error)
```

I don't want to call super, and have it validate and send errors to password2, so I am calling the post_clean method of the grandparent (ModelForm) instead (I think!), to not suffer consequences of leaving anything that does out. Then validating and sending errors to password1 instead.

This is the post_clean() method for UserCreationForm for comparison:

```
def _post_clean(self):
    super()._post_clean()
    # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
    # by super().
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
    if password:
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
        except ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password2', error)
```

On the surface this seems to work the way I want it to, but I am not very confident when it comes to overriding methods – I'm scared there will be weird side effects.

So my question is, is this ok? And do you know what I mean about wanting to show the errors for password1 instead? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried your solution? What you have got? Errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: Yep I have, and it seems to work, I just wanted to get other opinions and advice - sometimes there can be problems you don't notice on the surface/initially.

Answer (score 2):

- When you want to override a method, it's good to see the documentation for the method that you want to override.
- In most cases when overriding the default methods, `*args, **kwargs` will have higher affect.

In major cases, we have to make sure while overriding methods which take args and kwargs.Most common error is arguments mismatch. `*args` (arguments, ex: `def function(1,2,3)`) and `**kwargs` (keyword arguments, ex: `def function(name='sam', age=25)`) are the dynamic parameters to the function. When you define function without `*args`, `**kwargs` it has a fixed number of inputs which means it cannot accept more (or less) than you defined in the function. `*args` is a **tuple** and `**kwargs` is a **dictionary**. Here, [Read more about *args and **kwargs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/11282077).

It is also important that the order of doing things as it may have side affects or errors. Anyway it depends on the method.

Think this way:

- You are overriding `UserCreationForm`, Django default registration form. This will affect wherever registration is used.
- `_post_clean(self)` belongs to `UserCreationForm` which will affect wherever django registration is used.

Q. How your edits will affect the default behaviour?

A. You are changing the password validation (just changing the fontend behaviour). No matter whether it is password1 or password2, it won't affect anything because both passwords will be matched and sent to backend. So yes, it is completely ok in this scenario. Self will reffer to `UserCreationForm`, so it won't affect other ModelForm instances.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance :-) I was calling super on ModelForm (rather than the default, UserCreationForm) to avoid the validation happening on password2. That happens in UserCreationForm, but not ModelForm. I just tried the code you sent and now I get error messages for both password fields. I only want to show them for password1.

Comment: did you try modelform. what was the result then? Also would you specify the error

Comment: When I do super(forms.ModelForm, self)._post_clean() as in my original post, I get the desired behaviour. (validation errors for password1 only). When I use the code you sent, I receive the same validation errors for both password1 and password2. Sorry I should have made that clearer. The errors are expected, I just only want to show them for password1. I do achieve this with my original code, I just wanted to check there wouldn't be side effects.

Comment: Modified the answer. Self will reffer to UserCreationForm. So, Yes, it won't affect any other ModelForm instances.

Comment: Please could you provide clarification on this statement: "In most cases when overriding the default methods, *args, **kwargs will have higher affect."?

Comment: I've just realised, I think I should change from: super(forms.ModelForm, self)._post_clean() to: super(UserCreationForm, self)._post_clean(). I want to call the _post_clean() method in the parent of UserCreationForm, which is ModelForm. I don't want to call the method in the superclass of ModelForm, because then I would miss out on the functionality inside ModelForm's _post_clean() method.

Comment: (Apologies for all the comments). In theory this is true I think, but ModelForm doesn't define _post_clean() (it just has pass inside the definition), so super(forms.ModelForm, self)._post_clean() and super(UserCreationForm, self)._post_clean() have the same effect in this case. I think I'm getting to grips with super now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227873/discussion-between-siva-sankar-and-ffion).